# How to make use of Tags property of an xml node to get its information and attributes?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, xml-attribute

How would I make use of the Tags property of a node, so that I can get the attributes of an xml node?

I have to display an xml tree in a Windows Form. When I click on any node, its attributes should get displayed on a list box in same form.

I want to make use of tags property, but I need to convert that tree node in the form into an xml node. I wanted to store the tree node in the tag and then typecast that tag to an xml node.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

When adding the TreeNode class, your code would look like this:

```
// Create the node.
TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();

// Configure.
...

// Set the tag property to hold the XML element.
XmlElement currentElement = ...;
newNode.Tag = currentElement;

// Add to the tree view.
...
```

Then when you have the tree view node, you would get the element like this:

```
TreeNode currentNode = ...;

// Get the XmlElement.
XmlElement currentElement = (XmlElement) currentNode.Tag;

// Process the element.
...
```

Comment: can u please fill up your blanks? and also to fetch the attributes i use the event handler treeview_AfterSelect, so second part of your code would be written there?